# VBA doing a Vlookup and then a vbyesno box

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, vlookup

I have written a VBA that does a Vlookup. It is looking up claim numbers and each caim has a hyperlink in column 3 of the range that leads to the details of the claim, pics etc. The Vlookup returns the relevant hyperlink in column 3 fine, but then I want a vbyesno box to give the user the option to be directed to the hyperlink returned by the Vlookup and view the claim details.
I have managed to get it working OK to direct people to a web address (I have used google in my VBA as as example) Is it possible to change my VBA slightly so instead of google it will change the hyperlink depending on the result of the vlookup.

This is the VBA i have written

```
Sub check()

On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler:
Dim claim_number As String
Dim here    As String
claim_number = InputBox("please enter claim number")
If Len(claim_number) > 0 Then
    Set myRange = Range("claims")
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    here = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(claim_number, myRange, 3, False)
    intMessage = MsgBox("The claim has been partly investigated by Ali.  Would"
                        "you like to view the details of the claim.", _
                        vbYesNo, "Great news Lee")

    If intMessage = vbYes Then
        objShell.Run ("www.google.com")
    Else
        Wscript.Quit
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "You didn't enter a claim number"
End If
Exit Sub

MyerrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Claim has not been invsetigated"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Without knowing your source data, I can tell you that you can grab the hyperlink address from a cell with `cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address`, so `objShell.Run (cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address)` should do the trick. Just replace `cell` with wherever the hyperlink is in your worksheet.

Comment: The cell that the hyperlink is in will change. The Vlookup will return the cell with the relevant hyperlink in it. How can i get it to just use the Vlookup result cell to get the hyperlink

Comment: `objShell.Run(here)` ?

Comment: yes. i need it to go to (here) and direct to the hyperlink in that cell

Comment: Assuming `myrange` starts in row 1, try this: `objShell.Run (Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(claim_number, myrange, 0), 3).Hyperlinks(1).Address)`

Comment: Is your code in Excel exactly as you have here? Your `msgbox` is not formatted correctly, and I think  you need to remove the `:` from the first line, `On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler:`

Comment: yes my code is exactly as written here. Myrange does start in row 1. I've removed the : from the first line and its made no difference.

Comment: objShell.Run (Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(claim_number, myrange, 0), 3).Hyperlinks(1).Address) Doesn't  work either, i just get the :claim has not been investigated error at the end instead of being directed to the relevant hyperlink

Comment: The text box works fine. the only bit that i cannot get to work is the last bit that will direct you to the hyperlink in the cell returned by the Vlookup (here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys. I've managed to resolve the issue.
I just used ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (here)

as shown below

```
Sub check()


On Error GoTo MyerrorHandler
Dim claim_number As String
Dim here As String
claim_number = InputBox("Please enter the claim number")
If Len(claim_number) > 0 Then
Set myrange = Range("claims")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
here = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(claim_number, myrange, 3, 
False)
intMessage = MsgBox("This claim has been investigated by Ali.  Would you 
like to view the details?", _
vbYesNo, "GREAT NEWS LEE")

If intMessage = vbYes Then
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink (here)
Else
Wscript.Quit
End If

Else
MsgBox "You didn't enter a claim number"
End If
Exit Sub

MyerrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
MsgBox "This claim has not been investigated"
End If
```

End Sub